# clickhouse replica/server is not able to connect to each other when setting up a clickhouse 3 node circular cluster using zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, clickhouse

Data is not getting replicated to each clickhouse replica. While checking clickhouse-server log it is showing

**DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::queueTask()::: Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 0, e.displayText() = Host not found: ip-172-1-140-243 (version 19.9.2.4)**

I have 3 different machines on each machine I've installed both clickhouse and zookeeper. I'm trying to setup 3 node clickhouse cluster using zookeeper. I have followed these steps for configuration https://blog.uiza.io/replicated-and-distributed-on-clickhouse-part-2/ . I have created tables and replicas on all clickhouse instances and verified in zookeeper as well. Directory got created in zookeeper for all replicas. Have created /etc/metrica.xml , zoo.cfg , /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml on all instances. Providing all 3 files from 1 instance

/etc/metrica.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<yandex>
<clickhouse_remote_servers>
    <perftest_3shards_1replicas>
        <shard>
             <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
            <replica>
                <default_database>dwh01</default_database>
                <host>172.1.34.199</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
            <replica>
                <default_database>dwh01</default_database>
                <host>172.1.73.156</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
        </shard>

         <shard>
             <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
            <replica>
                <default_database>dwh02</default_database>
                <host>172.1.73.156</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
            <replica>
                <default_database>dwh02</default_database>
                <host>172.1.140.243</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
        </shard>

        <shard>
             <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
            <replica>
                <default_database>dwh03</default_database>
                <host>172.1.140.243</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
            <replica>
                <default_database>dwh03</default_database>
                <host>172.1.34.199</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
        </shard>
    </perftest_3shards_1replicas>
</clickhouse_remote_servers>


<zookeeper-servers>
  <node index="1">
    <host>172.1.34.199</host>
    <port>2181</port>
  </node>
 <node index="2">
    <host>172.1.73.156</host>
    <port>2181</port>
  </node>
 <node index="3">
    <host>172.1.140.243</host>
    <port>2181</port>
  </node> 
</zookeeper-servers>

<macros replace="replace">
  <cluster>OLAPLab</cluster>
  <dwhshard00>01</dwhshard00>
  <dwhshard01>03</dwhshard01>
  <dwhreplica00>01</dwhreplica00>
  <dwhreplica01>02</dwhreplica01>
  <shard>01</shard>
  <replica>node1</replica>
</macros>
<interserver_http_host>ip-172-1-34-199</interserver_http_host>
</yandex>
```

/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml

```
Only added this line rest of the config is default config
<listen_host>::</listen_host>
```

/usr/lib/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg

```
maxClientCnxns=50
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial 
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between 
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# the directory where the transaction logs are stored.
dataLogDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
server.1=172.1.34.199:2888:3888
server.2=172.1.73.156:2888:3888
server.3=172.1.140.243:2888:3888
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
127.0.0.1    ip-172-1-34-199
127.0.0.1    172.1.34.199
```

What should I change to get replicated data in all replicas belongs to all instances

Comment: It looks like you need to add to *hosts*-file of both nodes (*172.1.34.199* and *172.1.73.156*) the string *172.1.140.243 ip-172-1-140-243*.

Comment: JFY ["Do not run ZooKeeper on the same servers as ClickHouse. Because ZooKeeper is very sensitive for latency and ClickHouse may utilize all available system resources"](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/tips/#zookeeper).

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I've added all three hostnames in all three server's /etc/hosts file. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to add to *hosts*-file of both nodes (*172.1.34.199* and *172.1.73.156*) the string

```
172.1.140.243 ip-172-1-140-243
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the clickhouse and zookeeper ports accessible among the machines ?

As in, can you run `wget http://172.1.140.243:9000` ? Same applies to the zookeper ports respectively.

Comment: Yes ports are accessible. Yes I have tried doing telnet and using wget I'm able to hit. Issue got resolved after adding all three hostnames in hosts file of all three servers as mentioned by vladimir in his comment.